# just making sure this is efficient, for the null checks

Tags: c#

This is inside a method (basically its just this), I try to get the neededValue otherwise I pass back what was passed in...

```
private static string GetNeededValue(string param)
    {
        string tValue = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
        {
            var map = repo.Item(string.Format("CoverageName LIKE '{0}'",param));
            tValue = map == null ? param : map.theNeededValue;
        }

        return tValue;            
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it seems fine from an efficiency point of view. Here's a couple of simple alternatives you could consider.

Remove the need for the ! condition.  I quite like this option as I think it flows nicely and is easy to read.

```
private static string GetNeededValue(string param)
{
   // do we care about whitespace.  If so you could use IsNullOrWhiteSpace
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)) return param;

   var map = repo.Item(string.Format("CoverageName LIKE '{0}'",param));
   return map == null ? param : map.theNeededValue; 
}
```

Or another alternative might be to be more explicit about when tValue is set.

```
private static string GetNeededValue(string param)
{
   var tValue = param;

   // do we care about whitespace.  If so you could use IsNullOrWhiteSpace
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tValue))

      var map = repo.Item(string.Format("CoverageName LIKE '{0}'",tValue));

      if(map != null)
         tValue = map.theNeededValue;  
   }

   return tValue;
}
```

Comment: +1 The first option is exactly how I would write this. (minus the sql injection flaw of course)

Comment: repo.item is using datatable.Select, so SQL injection is not possible

Comment: @Spooks excellent!

Comment: To be honest, I prefer the way Spook originally formatted his code – I think that `!` is very easy to read and that the `if` block is easy to understand. Of course, this means that it's completely subjective which way is best.

Comment: @Kevin  Yep they all have their merits and each is probably preferred between individuals.  I must admit I've often written code myself that way so often it depends on how I'm thinking about the problem at the time...

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's efficient. However, your code appears to be very vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. For example, imagine what the result would be if a user ran this code:

```
var result = MyModule.GetNeededValue("' OR '0' <> '1");
```

or worse

```
var result = MyModule.GetNeededValue("';DROP TABLE foo--");
```

To fix this flaw, it should be easy enough to rewrite the `repo.Item` method to support a call like this using parameters in a prepared statement rather than dynamic SQL:

```
var map = repo.Item("CoverageName LIKE @p1", param);
```

Comment: ah, it would look that way. the actually parameter is being grabbed from a database table that only admin has access to. Though something to think about

Comment: +1 good point about the sql injection comment.  Always something to consider....

Comment: Oh found out repo.item is using datatable.Select, so SQL injection is not possible

Comment: @Spooks That's definitely better, but I think you could still be susceptible to the first kind of query I mentioned.

Comment: @p.s.w.g that does seem possible,though its a fixed list, so if someone wanted to change it they would need access to the database though.  I would definitely use parameters in a prepared statement otherwise

Comment: It still is worth refactoring out the potential attack because if this method is used elsewhere that is vulnerable later on, it would be extremely difficult to  fix.

Comment: good point, refactored

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that returning `""` means "You gave me garbage so here is some garbage." I have been working hard on pulling myself out of this same habit I have developed over the years. This method is a great example as it can have its domain tightened. Also because it is private it can possibly have that `IsNullOrEmpty` check removed entirely in a release build.

```
private static string GetNeededValue(string param)
{
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)); // [ConditionalAttribute("CONTRACTS_FULL")]
    var map = repo.Item(string.Concat("CoverageName LIKE '",param,'\''));
    return = map == null ? param : map.theNeededValue;
}
```

The tooling to support the Contract methods can be found here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/ .